# Binding Data to Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I currently have a URL request the brings back XML data. I store that data in a document that is read and finds the information between certain attributes, and assigns those values to the my assigned variables. my wpf DataGrid is called Movie_DataGrid. Any help would be great on how to get this data to the DataGrid.

-- EDIT --

I updated my code with a new way i am trying to get my results. When stepping through each step of the code, the XML is storing fine, and all tag attributes between the Retrivalinfo class and the Retrievalinfo convertedMovie = new Retrievalinfo() are the same, but application errors out at this method.

My new issue is, the values within the attributes is not being grabbed and stored. I have also put a sample of what XML I would get back.

```
<root response="True">
<movie title="Up in the Air" year="2009" rated="R" released="23 Dec 2009" runtime="109 
min" genre="Drama, Romance" director="Jason Reitman" writer="Walter Kirn (novel), Jason
Reitman (screenplay), Sheldon Turner (screenplay)" actors="George Clooney, Vera Farmiga,
Anna Kendrick, Jason Bateman" plot="With a job that has him traveling around the country
firing people, Ryan Bingham leads an empty life out of a suitcase, until his company
does the unexpected: ground him." language="English" country="USA" awards="Nominated for
6 Oscars. Another 64 wins & 66 nominations."poster="http://ia.mediaimdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI3MzYxMTA4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMD
E4ODg3Mg@@._V1_SX300.jpg" metascore="83" imdbRating="7.5" imdbVotes="215,961" imdbID="tt1193138" type="movie"/>
</root>    


     // This action will seach the IMDb API for the associated infromation for the IMDBID that is tagged with the title you chose in the ListBox.
     private void Movie_List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {   // Grabs the IMDBID associated to the movie title selected to be used with the second API request.
        var p = Movie_List.SelectedIndex;

        string titleID = structholder[p].IMDBID;

        // Prepares 2nd API URL request to get data for chosen title.
        // Creates a XML Document  to store the xml data that was sent back by the API.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + titleID + "&r=XML");

        // Creates a XML Noedlist to store the values that are going to be associated with the given attribute tag.
        XmlNodeList movieList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("movie");

        var movie = movieList.Item(0);

        Retrievalinfo convertedMovie = new Retrievalinfo()
        {
            title = movie.Attributes["title"].ToString(),
            actors = movie.Attributes["actors"].ToString().Split(',').ToList(),
            genre = movie.Attributes["genre"].ToString(),
            rated = movie.Attributes["rated"].ToString(),
            imdbRating = movie.Attributes["imbdRating"].ToString(),
            released = movie.Attributes["released"].ToString(),
            runtime = movie.Attributes["runtime"].ToString(),
        };

        List<Retrievalinfo> gridInfo = new List<Retrievalinfo>();
        Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = gridInfo;
```

---

---

Here is the class where each variable is stored that I want to display in the DataGrid.

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class Retrievalinfo
    {
       public Retrievalinfo()
        {
            actors = new List<string>();
        }

        //Creating a list of info objects that will store all returned data for selected title.
        public string title; 
        public List<string> actors; 
        public string genre;
        public string rated;
        public string imdbRating; 
        public string released; 
        public string runtime;

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I though of writing a lengthy aswer but instead, here's a quick sample for you that you can use as reference and figure out the details yourself. MVVM not included :D

Hope it helps.

**Codebehind**

```
namespace MyMovies
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Movies = new ObservableCollection<Movie>()
                {
                    new Movie("Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels", 4),
                    new Movie("Life of Brian", 5),
                };

            var addMovieCommand = new RoutedUICommand();
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window),
                new CommandBinding(
                    addMovieCommand,
                    (sender, args) => AddMovie(),
                    (sender, args) => args.CanExecute = true));
            AddMovieCommand = addMovieCommand;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        public ICommand AddMovieCommand { get; set; }

        private void AddMovie()
        {
            Movies.Add(new Movie(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 3));
        }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie(string name, int stars)
        {
            Name = name;
            Stars = stars;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MyMovies.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}">
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Content="Add movie" Command="{Binding AddMovieCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Which gives you

[image: notfound]

Comment: I have the first block of code for getting and reading the XML as a doubleclick action on the title inside of a list (which populates with search titles form the search box) so what i need to know is how to make my Retrivalinfo class an ObserableCollection, as long as the other code is properly assigning values to it

Comment: On your DoubleClick pass results (collection of retrieval info instances) to observablecollection property in code behind. And after that raise onpropertychanged on that property to notify the UI of changes. You should also consider implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on RetrievalInfo class, too.

Comment: @user3280210 Change public fields in your RetrievalInfo as automatic properties and that should do it. For example 
public string title; 
becomes 
public string title { get; set; }

Comment: I have made changes to my original code and gave sample xml

Comment: @user3280210 Did you find the answer helpfull?

Comment: Yes some but still trying to piece together our sets of code to get it to work with the remaining code I have

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need a few pieces:

- An `ObservableCollection<RetrievalInfo>` in your view model to store the retrieved data
- A Datagrid (or perhaps a grid view) in your XAML that has its item source bound to the above property
- Columns in the above control to represent each of your data pieces.
- The retrieval code should modify the observable collection so they appear on your UI

I would be happy to provide samples for any or all of those pieces that you aren't sure how to implement.

Comment: Note that your code is very close to this (without the MVVM and XAML pieces), but you shouldn't rebind the ItemsSource to a new collection every time. Instead, each retrieval should add a new entry to a persistent (class level?) observable collection.

Comment: Each time the user searches a movie, then selects the proper title, I want just one row of data to be returned. They then will press export, to their respective locations. I would need to do some changing to let them search a movie, populate DataGrid based on choice, clear titles from list and question from search bar, but leave data in Grid, Repeat

Comment: your comment is correct. Also I just cant seem to see how to create an ObserableCollection out of my RetrivalInfo class as it also has a list of strings in it for authors.

Comment: If you only want one row of data, data grid might not be your best choice. Regardless, what does the list of strings do that is preventing you from creating an ObservableCollection?

Comment: I have made changes to my original code and gave sample xml. I also like the idea of being able to do multiple searches and have multiple lines of data in the data grid.

Comment: I see the updated code, but could you describe what still isn't working/ what you still need help with?

Comment: I cannot get the list "gridInfo" to bind and display to the DataGrid when I run the Application

Comment: I will assume you are can hit a breakpoint in your function (though given that it is on selectionChanged, I would make sure of that). I would try making your source list a class (as opposed to function) member, make sure it is not empty  when you create it, and perhaps try a normal WPF binding instead of setting ItemsSource programmatically. If any of these help, I will happily update my answer to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the xml to List of object using the code snippet provided in the following Blog

**Blog Link:**

http://danielwylie.me/blog/2010/04/c-convert-xml-to-an-object-or-list-of-an-object

You can assign the ItemSource of dataGrid by using the following code snippet

```
Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
        //here list object from  public static List<T> XmlToObjectList<T>(string xml, string nodePath)  method
```